# How to copy files from azure Devops to Azure file share storage account

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-storage, azure-storage-account, fileshare

I have a build pipeline which builds *.p12 files and been published a artifacts in the build pipeline

How to copy files from azure Devops pipeline workspace or from published artifacts to Azure storage account (Fileshare) path

Comment: You can use the REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob

Comment: I am looking for to put in fileshare , the above reference is for blobs , @MarkusMeyer

Comment: OK, this one is for files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file

Answer (score 2):

“Az storage file upload “ az cli command works to upload files from azure Devops pipeline workspace to fileshare storage account

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could [Azure file copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops) in Azure pipeline to copy file from Azure pipeline to azure storage account. This task works only when run on Windows agents.

[image]

Comment: This can upload to only blob , was looking for to upload to fileshare location, but then “az storage file upload” az cli worked

Answer (score 0):

[Az storage file upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-file-upload) is what y'all are looking for. Batch upload can be used to do files instead of directories. Despite what the website says a combination of connection string and share name will also work.

Since it took me a while to find it, here is the command to get the connection string and then reuse it later:

`connectionString=$(az storage account show-connection-string -g **name of your resource group** -n **name of storage account** --query connectionString -o tsv )`